# Proper way of adding to overview answers

Tags: discussion, overview-questions

What should I do in list/overview question like this one: [What is an overview of Christian viewpoints on the eternal destiny of individuals who die never hearing the Gospel?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79245/what-is-an-overview-of-christian-viewpoints-on-the-eternal-destiny-of-individual)

when I think a smaller denomination (let's be frank, I mean The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints) would be a good addition because of notably different doctrine?

The issue I have is:

- There is no point in making a new answer that also includes already well covered denominations, since I know less about those than the users who already answered. The answer can only get worse, or has to copy a lot of the existing answers.
- Creating a new answer just for one viewpoint doesn't feel right because it's not an overview over multiple denominations as the question asks. Doing it this way would also make it impossible or hard to choose an answer to accept.
- Editing an existing answer with an additional viewpoint is a pretty big change that feels very intrusive. I don't think I would like such major changes to happen to my answers, so I am reluctant to do something like that.
- Asking someone to add to their answer also doesn't work, how can I expect one person to know or research everything?

In general I think it is reasonable to include viewpoints outside of catholic/orthodox/protestant, I am sure it is interesting to learn about, let's say, what Jehovahs Witnesses believe even if one doesn't necessarily agree. But nobody can expect someone who can give a good catholic answer to also be able to give a good JW or LDS answer, or the other way around. But at the same time, I don't think it is reasonable to sort of drown the "major" viewpoints in lots of "minor" ones (the terminology doesn't feel right but you get what I mean).

What is your opinion on this problem? How should one go about adding onto overview answers?

Comment: I think asking one of the other answerers if you can edit their answer to add more information would be great. When it's an overview question they'll probably be grateful for the help and say yes.

Comment: @curiousdannii I did just that and exactly what you described happened. Thanks :-)